# Pip not installing Python modules to proper directory

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-2.7

So I downloaded a module, but when I tried to use it in a program, Python threw the error:
"ImportError: No module named markovify"

When I go to try to change my .bash_profile, it shows this:

"# Setting PATH for Python 3.5

## The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH"

I've been using 2.7.10 all this time, and Terminal defaults to it. (When I type in Python, that's the version it says I'm using)

I'm trying to get pip to install modules for python 2.7.10 to a different folder.

What's weird is this: I seem to have installed pyparsing with pip and it seems to work. I tried installing markovify and it throws this error message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your PATH seems to be for python 3.5 not 2.7 (sorry, I never have used OSX).

Comment: Why is your profile printing things?

Answer (score 0):

> When I go to try to change my .bash_profile, it prints this

That suggests you're using some tool to change your profile.  Did you also use that tool to install markovify?  You need to be clear about your environment when you have environment questions!  :-)

If you installed markovify from the command line, I'd suggest opening a new terminal and running these commands, just to make sure you're working from where you think you are:

```
$ python --version 
Python 2.7.10
$ command -v python
/usr/bin/python
```

The most likely problem, it seems to me, is that you got a bit tangled up and wound up doing something other than what you intended.  From a fresh start, provided you're starting with the environment you want, pip should, you know, Just Work.

> I'm trying to get pip to install modules for python 2.7.10 to a different folder.

That's possible to do, but are you sure that's what you want?  Usually if you're using the Python interpreter you intend to, and haven't putzed with PYTHON_PATH & friends, when you run **pip**, it will install to its default location, which sure enough is where Python will look for it when you say to import it.

As an experiment, you might check if markovify was somehow installed for Python 3.5.  Try

```
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python -c 'import markovify'
```

(You might also want to check that the Python interpreter is in fact in that folder and has that name.)

Comment: OK, I found that markovify was indeed saved to:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages along with pyparser, which does work. 

I copied it to: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and I'm slammin markov jibberish like it's my job. But this only seems to be a temporary solution. I would still like to know why this didn't work. How on earth c

Answer (score 0):

When you're working on more than one Python version, you should work on Virtual Environments:
[Virtual Env on Hitchhiker's Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: I really would just prefer to use one version. Is there a way to get rid of 3.5?